# concatenate variable + string gives TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python-3.x, list

following code:

```
    def main():

        folder = []

        if f_args.course == 1:
            folder = "C90-01"
        elif f_args.course == 2:
            folder = "C90-02"
        elif f_args.course == 3:
            folder = "C90-03"
        sources = glob(folder + '/*.pdf')

        print(sources)
```

this results in a "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list" error.
What I need is basically:
Based on the argument the script needs to make a list out of all PDF files in this directory for further processing.

when I do a

```
sources = []
if f_args.course == 1:
sources = glob('C90-01/*.pdf')
elif f_args.course == 2:
sources = glob("C90-02/*.pdf")
```

I get an empty list []

but when I do a

```
print(glob('C90-01/*.pdf'))
```

it works

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Why are you doing `folder = []`? If all the checks fail, folder won't be overwritten and will remain a list. As the error says, you can't concatenate a list and string. Do you mean `folder = "" `?

Comment: without folder = [] I got a "variable referenced before declared" error. doing a folder = "" gives me a [] as the result of "print(sources)

Comment: if I do "sources = glob(C90-01/*.pdf" everything works perfectly fine, but the folder to look into changes based on the argument given

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398993/typeerror-can-only-concatenate-list-not-str-to-list)

Comment: @mx0 I don't want to add / remove things from an existing list. I'm trying to build the list based on glob. When I do a print(glob('C90-01/*.pdf')) it works perfectly fine. I edited my original question

Answer (score 0):

found the problem.
it needs to be

if f_args.course =='1'

I simply forgot the ''