# Append list to list in specific cell in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, which looks like this:

```
   key   arr 
a  't1' [1,2]
b  't2' [3,4]
```

And I want to append a new list c = [5,6] to the row, where

```
row['key'] == 't1'
```

So the result would be:

```
   key   arr 
a  't1' [1,2,5,6]
b  't2' [3,4]
```

Right now my attempt looks like this:

```
df.loc[df['key'] == label]['arr'] = df.loc[df['key'] == 't1']['arr'] + c
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398993/typeerror-can-only-concatenate-list-not-str-to-list)

Comment: But there should not be a string in this dataframe. So I waswondering if the concatination with + is somehow not the right one. Ill check again the types.

Comment: Could you share how `c` is defined? maybe you overwrite it?

Comment: c is actually a value retrieved from another dataframe, generated by external library. I assumed it must be an array but when checking again the types it gives me, I noticed that it is actually a string. I will edit this ticket therefore as it does not help anyone here otherwise and it has already answers so I wont delete it. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @EveEdomenko Can you post `c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is use list comprehension with `+`:

```
import ast

c = [5,6]
#if necessary
#df['arr'] = df['arr'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
m = df['key'] == 't1'
df.loc[m, 'arr'] = [x+c for x in df.loc[m, 'arr']]

print (df)
  key           arr
a  t1  [1, 2, 5, 6]
b  t2        [3, 4]
```

Or you can create new `Series` with `np.repeat` and filtered index values by mask and add by `+=`:

```
m = df['key'] == 't1'

df.loc[m, 'arr'] += pd.Series(np.repeat([c], m.sum(), axis=0).tolist(), index=df.index[m])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
c = [5,6]
i = df[df['key']=='t1'].index.values[0]
df['arr'][i]+=c

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  key           arr
a  t1  [1, 2, 5, 6]
b  t2        [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below snippet:

```
df.loc[df['key'] == label]['arr'] = df.loc[df['key'] == 't1']['arr'].extend(c)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'extend'`